# Ionic Components Not Loading?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework, gulp

I've spent a ton of time banging my head against the wall here and I can't quite seem to figure out where my issue lies. Essentially I am working on a simple application to display some data from a local storage SQLite DB (this works fine) for my company. I developed this used the Ionic CLI tools and create a fully functional application. Shown here, with some info blurred out for obvious reasons:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/59ARZ.jpg

After development, the final step of development was to get the project integrated with our team's gulp build system. We are using browserify to create our styles.css and bundle.js file. The home.html page is routed to, as expected, but it seems that the ionic css components are not being loaded properly? Shown above (I lack 10 reputation to post images):

We are loading the ionic scss pages here - ionic.app.scss:

```
$ionicons-font-path: "../../../node_modules/ionic/fonts" !default;

// Include all of Ionic
@import "../../../node_modules/ionic/scss/ionic";
```

And then these get imported to the rest of our main.scss file here:

```
@import "ionic.app.scss";
```

I've been sure to check both the x-code and remote debugger console respectively. Neither contain any errors, shown below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/E606T.jpg

Edit: I hope I hit all the bits of information that would be needed. Appreciate any help you all could provide as I'm out of ideas that could be causing this problem.